# How to start matlab daemon

Tags: macos, python, matlab, plist

I have a plist calling a python script every day. The python script calls different matlab routines depending on their success. This works perfectly fine when I'm using the computer but when I'm not using it the daemon gives me following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/<username>/Documents/daemontest/matlab_batcher.py", line 108, in <module>
    eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matlab/engine/__init__.py", line 92, in start_matlab
    eng = MatlabEngine(option)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matlab/engine/matlabengine.py", line 230, in __init__
    self.__dict__["_matlab"] = pythonengine.createMATLAB(tokens)
matlab.engine.EngineError: MATLAB process can not be created.
```

I ticked "prevent computer from sleeping" and unticked "enable power nap" in the energy saving preferences so I beliefe the computer does not go to sleep. Still it cannot start matlab.

Might the problem be a matlab license issue? How can I start matlab without me being "active" or logged on?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out a solution, well, rather a work around.

In the python script I was using MatlabEngine by matlab. Apparently this only starts when the user is active. The details I still don't know but must be something ado with the matlab license and the model the imac switches to a few minutes after the user becomes inactive. Would be interesting though to understand this properly...

What actually works is to use bash commands instead of the MatlabEngine for calling matlab. This doesn't offer the direct interaction with matlab function as the MatlabEngine but for my case totally sufficient.